# The limit of the convergent Fourier series of $f$ is $f$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have to try and solve the following question:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[-\pi,\pi].$ Suppose that the Fourier series converges uniformly. Then its limit must be $f.$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Say $\sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$ converges uniformly to $L(\theta).$ Then,
$$\sum_{n=-N}^N r^{|n|}\hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$$ converges uniformly for $r\rightarrow 1^-$ to $L(\theta).$

Since $f$ is continuous, by Poisson's Theorem we have that $\sum_{n=-N}^N r^{|n|}\hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$ converges uniformly to $f(\theta)$ as $r\rightarrow 1^-.$ So $L(\theta)=f(\theta),$ for all $\theta.$

---

I'm worried about a logical flaw in my attempt or an overlook of some property of uniform convergence. Also, the exercise comes with the hint:

> **HINT:** *Calculate the Fourier coefficients of the limit function.*

Now, I haven't used this idea my attempt and really would like some help getting this approved/rectified, I would really appreciate any help! Thank you so much!

**P.S.** Going with the hint, I thought maybe I could use the fact that if all the Fourier coefficients are the same for two functions, then the functions are identical at all points; I ended up at a dead-end here though.

Comment: Let $g$ the limit; integrating term by term (allowed by uniform convergence) shows that $g$ has same Fourier coefficients as $f$ so done

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain what to integrate term by term?

Comment: by defintion $g(\theta)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$, so,$2\pi \hat{g}(m)=\int_0^{2\pi}g(\theta)e^{-im\theta}d \theta=\int_0^{2\pi}(\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta})e^{-im\theta}d \theta$, but by uniform continuity you can switch sum with integral, so integrate term by term and then all terms but the $m$th one cancel out by orthogonality, so you get $\hat{g}(m)=\hat{f}(m)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Fourier Series for $f$ converges uniformly to $g$, then $g$ is continuous and
\begin{align}
          \hat{g}(n)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)e^{-inx}dx \\
    &=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sum_{k=-K}^{K}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}e^{-inx}dx \\
    &= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=-K}^{K}\hat{f}(k)\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(k-n)x}dx=\hat{f}(n).
\end{align}
Therefore, the Parseval identity gives $\int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)-g(x)|^2dx = 0$. So, the following holds for all $y$
$$
                0 \le \int_0^y|f(x)-g(x)|^2dx  \le \int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)-g(x)|^2dx =0.
$$
It follows that $\int_0^y|f(x)-g(x)|^2dx =0$ for all $0\le y\le 2\pi$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the derivative with respect to $y$ is $|f(y)-g(y)|^2$, which must be $0$. Therefore $f=g$.